# Как установить динамическую связь между двумя полями с radio?

Tags: php, ajax

Может вопрос прозвучал не совсем корректно, но сейчас все объясню. Имеется два див контейнера содержащие в себе лейблы с радио кнопками.

```
                    <!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <script ENGINE="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js "></script>
    <title>СПАСИТЕ</title>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        function callTime(){
        var master = document.getElementByName('master').value;
        var Polina_date = document.getElementByName('Polina_date').value;
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/array_master_time.php',
                data: (master: master, Polina_date: Polina_date),
                success: function(){
                    alert('Отправлено');
                }
            });
        });
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form action="php/rec.php" method="post">
            <div id="Page_center">
                <div class="employee">
                    <div class="section_name">
                        <snap class="section_text">Выберите мастера</snap>
                    </div>

                    <label class="employee_data">
                      <input type="radio" name="master" value="#desavir_Полина" required checked>
                        </label>
                    <label class="employee_data">
                      <input type="radio"  name="master" value="#desavir_pedi_Света">
                        </label>

                </div>
                <div class="date">
                    <div class="section_name">
                        <snap class="section_text">Выберите дату и время</snap>
                    </div>
                 <div class="select_box">
                  <div class="select_date_box">
                    <?php include "php/array_master.php";?> 
                    <div id="Polina" class="label_date_box">
                 <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {

               echo '<label class="label-date">
                        <input type="radio"  name="Polina_date" value=" '.$row['date'].' "  onClick = "callTime()">
                            <snap class="info_of_date">'.$row['date'].' </snap></label>';
                }?>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  <div class="select_time_box">
                    <?php 
                        include "php/array_master_time.php"; 
                    ?><div id="Polina_time" class="label_time_box">
                 <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t)) {

               echo '<label class="label-date">
                        <input type="radio"  name="Polina_time" value=" '.$row['time'].' ">
                            <snap class="info_of_time">'.$row['date'].' </snap></label>';
                }?>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Записаться" class="button_or" name="zapis_button">
                </div>
            </div>
         </form>

    </main>     
</body>
```

q1 - массив данных из БД, который берется следующим образом

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Света` WHERE date >='$today' ORDER BY date";
$q1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
```

t1 - массив данных из БД, который берется следующим образом

```
<?php
$master = $_POST['master'];
$date_Polina = $_POST['Polina_date'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `Полина` WHERE date ='$date_Polina'";
$t = mysqli_query($connect, $query); //Отправляем запрос?>
```

Контейнер содержащий время зависит от выбранной даты в первом контейнере( точнее, так должно быть). Ну и вроде бы логика верная: человек выбирает дату, вызывается функция onClick = "callTime()", ведь мы вроде как кликнули на радио, тем самым срабатывает скрипт в начале с $.ajax, который передает значение master, Polina_date, в php, но у меня почему то даже не выскакивает "Отправлено", что не так?

Comment: Начни с изучения JS https://learn.javascript.ru, все равно придется)

Comment: @NikitaUmnov я изучал C, поэтому с понимаем языков программирования у меня проблем нет,я вот сейчас нашел AJAX примеры по неявной передачи данных(без перезагрузки стр) но остались вопросы по поводу поля date в функции $.ajax, может вы поможете понять что является в этой форме наименованием передаваемого объекта, а что самим объектом data: ({master: 'master'})? Искал в документации но что то ничего не нашел...

Comment: не уверен, что понял вопрос. В data передается строка или объект c данными. Например `$.ajax({url: '/path/to/api', type: 'POST', Data: {date: '2020-02-19'}, success: ...})`

Comment: то есть в моем случае я с помощью функции "var Sveta_date = document.getElementByName('Sveta_date').value;" должен извлечь значение которое лежит в поле с именем 'Sveta_date' и после в функции $.ajax прописать Data: {Sveta_date: 'Sveta_date'} чтоб успешно передать значение ?

Comment: да, только `{Sveta_date: Sveta_date}`, без кавычек. Слева ключ, справа значение

Comment: @NikitaUmnov обидно, но нечего не вышло, видимо следует лучше разобраться в вопросе...

Comment: лучше будет выложить пример в какой нибудь песочнице и приложить здесь ссылку. проще будет понять где ошибка

Comment: @NikitaUmnov что то залить на GitHub не вышло, слишком сложно для моего ума. Постараюсь изменить вопрос добавив кода, чтоб стало понятнее.

Comment: @NikitaUmnov изменил исходный вопрос: предоставил полный код выкинув другие блоки не влияющие на взаимоотношение этих двух радио.

Comment: 1) url точно верный? возможно, нужен слеш в начале. 2) попробуй в $.ajax добавить `error: console.error`, чтобы посмотреть что пошло не так. Приложи что выдало в консоли 3) попробуй onclick заменить на onchange

Comment: только сейчас заметил: в url нужно указать url, а не путь к файлу на сервере

Comment: @NikitaUmnov Я понял что он в эту функцию даже не заходит. Попытался изменить на "$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input:radio[name=Polina_date]').change(function(){
         alert('1');..." и если я верно понял, то сразу после переключения мне должно было бы всплыть сообщение, но нет.

Comment: @Kirzzz ))) Всё гораздо проще )))

Comment: @Denis640Kb кажется я вам скинул не ту ссылку на вопрос... С этим я разобрался, но вышло для меня это совсем не просто [url](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084602/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)