# Как вернуть новую переменную из ajax запроса?

Tags: php, ajax

Имеется код с использованием ajax

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/php/array_master_time.php',
                data: { // что отправляем
                    "master": master, "Polina_date": Polina_date
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                    alert(51);
                }
            });
```

собственно код обработки этого запроса на php

```
if($_POST['master']&&$_POST['Polina_date'])
{
  $master = $_POST['master'];
  $date_Polina = $_POST['Polina_date'];


  $query = "SELECT * FROM `#desavir_Полина` WHERE date ='$date_Polina'";
  $t = mysqli_query($connect, $query); //Отправляем запрос 

  exit($t);
}
```

и то где в последствии должна использоваться $t

```
div id="Polina_time" class="label_time_box">
                 <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t)) {

               echo '<label class="label-date">
                        <input type="radio"  name="Polina_time" value=" '.$row['time'].' ">
                            <snap class="info_of_time">'.$row['date'].' </snap></label>';
                }?>
                    </div>
```

Задача состоит в том чтоб обновит переменную t на странице, содержащую в себе массив БД. Как это реализовать?  код на полный html [html](https://pastebin.com/ADE9mgxN) [php_time](https://pastebin.com/2GQTQDqP) [JAVA](https://pastebin.com/1r0GZ7wd)

Comment: Переменную t вы и так присвоили. Сделать-то что собирались? Выполнить запрос и вернуть его результаты в ajax?

Comment: Начну из далека. Имеется радио при выборе которого появляются соответствующие выборы даты выбранные из БД, даты выводятся также как ради для выбора. После выбора даты должно отображаться время которое также берется из БД(это переменная $t) и после с ней выполняется некий код. Так как при первой загрузке страницы эта t пуста, то после выбора даты она должна обновиться и выполнится часть кода с ней как я понимаю. И вернуть его результат в нужный мне кусок кода(я особо не разбираюсь, может достаточно просто вернуть его на html страницу обновленным и код сам чудом выполнится)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP:

```
if($_POST['master']&&$_POST['Polina_date'])
{
  $master = $_POST['master'];
  $date_Polina = $_POST['Polina_date'];


  $query = "SELECT * FROM `#desavir_Полина` WHERE date ='$date_Polina'";
  $t = mysqli_query($connect, $query); //Отправляем запрос 

  $output = $t->fetch_assoc(); // переводим результат запроса в ассоциативный массив
  print_r($output); // выводим этот результат на страницу

  exit($t);
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/php/array_master_time.php',
    data: { // что отправляем
        "master": master, "Polina_date": Polina_date
    },
    success: function(response) // в переменной response остаётся результат выполнения PHP скрипта
    {
        $("div#myResult").html(response); // div'у с id="myResult" меняем содержимое на то, что вывел скрипт
    }
});
```

Данное действие просто выведет ответ, который отдал MySQL запрос в виде читабельного текста.

Для последующего размещения необходимых данных по нужным блокам, используйте JSON:

PHP:

```
$output = $t->fetch_assoc(); // переводим результат запроса в ассоциативный массив
echo json_encode($output); // переводим массив в JSON-строку и выводим на страницу
```

JS:

```
success: function(response) {
    var output = JSON.parse(response);
    $("#block1").html(output.block1value);
    $("#block2").html(output.block2value);
    .....
}
```

`block1value` и `block2value` вставлены в качестве примера.

На деле, если запрос вернёт, например:

```
Array(
  'name' => 'Полина',
  'surname' => 'Петрова',
  'id' => 1
)
```

То код будет примерно таким:

```
success: function(response) {
    var output = JSON.parse(response);
    $("#username").html(output.name + " " + output.surname);
    $("#userid").html(output.id);
}
```

То есть в блок с `id="username"` вставится значение `Полина Петрова`, а в блок с `id="userid"` вставится `1`.

Comment: `$("#myResult).load(url, data)`;

Comment: Мой код с использованием $t выглядит вот так '<div id="Polina" class="label_date_box">
                     <?php  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q1)) {
     
                   echo '<label class="label-date" >
         <input type="radio"  name="Sveta1_date" value=" '.$row['date'].' ">
        <snap class="info_of_date">'.$row['date'].' </snap></label>';
                    }?>
              </div>' Если я передам значения в Див, то это все равно будет отображаться как текст, поэтому мне надо именно обновить переменную t, или поменять процесс вывода данных с t

Comment: @Kirzzz, в таком случае, если генерация HTML-кода происходит непосредственно в PHP-скрипте, то просто выведите переменную `$t` с помощью echo: `echo $t;`, и с помощью JS-скрипта разместите её в необходимом блоке: `success(response) {$("#block").html(response);}`.

Comment: @decotoev я уверен в том что это работает так как меня выкидывает с ошибкой (встроил в ajax ошибки) "Не найден домен в запросе [500]", интересно что это

Comment: @Kirzzz проверьте адрес, куда отсылаете AJAX-запрос (возможно виноваты относительные/абсолютные ссылки, протокол (http/https) или написали адрес с ошибкой). Если не поможет, попробуйте временно заменить содержимое PHP-скрипта на `<?php echo "test"; ?>`, чтобы понять, в чём именно ошибка – в JS или в PHP-скрипте.

Comment: @decotoev поступил как вы и сказали, из чего выяснилось, что ошибка в php, теперь осталось только понять где

Comment: @decotoev и я даже понял где, но в чем конкретно ошибка - нет...  после строки "$t=mysqli_query($connect, $query);" echo не выполняется

Comment: @Kirzzz, попробуйте заменить строку `$t=mysqli_query($connect, $query);` на `if(!$t = $connect->query($query)) {echo $connect->error;} else {echo print_r($t->fetch_assoc());}`. Какая ошибка появится?

Comment: @Dmitry страница опять выкинула ошибку 500 и не вывела echo $connect->error;

Comment: @Kirzzz, соединение с MySQL в переменной $connect установлено? Перед SQL-запросом пропишите: `if(!$connect = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','database')) die($connect->error);`. Только свои значения хоста, пользователя, пароля и базы данных поставьте.

Comment: @Dmitry Да, разумеется, я уже это проверил 100 раз

Comment: @Kirzzz можете выложить код полностью, скажем, на pastebin?

Comment: @Dmitry сейчас так и поступлю тогда

Comment: @Dmitry прикрепил ссылки к вопросу

Comment: @Kirzzz попробуйте переименовать таблицы, убрав из названия символ решётки (#), а так же в `ORDER BY time` оберните `time` в обратные кавычки ( ` )

Comment: @Dmitry если вы видели тот код что я прикрепил, то обратили внимание на поля для дат, так вот, SQL запрос для получения из БД дат точно такой же, как и тот что используется для времени только в одном указано поле date, а в другом time. Поэтому думаю это не поможет

Comment: @Kirzzz каких-то явных ошибок в приложенном Вами коде я не вижу. Но я бы всё равно не советовал использовать спецсимволы, русские символы и зарезервированные слова в именах баз, таблиц и столбцов, так как поведение скриптов в данных случаях крайне нестабильно. Обратные кавычки используются как раз для того, чтобы отделять служебные слова от имён. Рекомендую ознакомиться: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Reserved_words.html и http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Legal_names.html