# В чем ошибка в данном php скрипте?

Tags: php, ajax

есть php скрипт который вызывается от ajax, в ajax есть некие поля ошибок и мне кидает вот эту "Не найден доман в запросе [500]". Сейчас подробнее: вот кусок с ajax, и он рабочий, позже объясню почему.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'php/array_master_time.php',
                data: { 
                    "master": master, "Polina_date": Polina_date
                },
                success: function(response)
                {
                  $("#Polina_time").html(response);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, exception)...
```

а вот якобы проблемный кусок кода PHP

```
if($_POST['master'] && $_POST['Polina_date'])
{

  $master = $_POST['master'];
  $date_Polina = $_POST['Polina_date'];

  $query = "SELECT time FROM `#desavir_Полина` WHERE date ='$date_Polina' ORDER BY time";
  $t = mysqli_query($connect, $query); //Отправляем запрос 

  $output = $t_fetch_assoc(); // переводим результат запроса в ассоциативный массив
  echo json_encode($output); 

  exit;
  /*$query_close();
  echo $t;
  exit;*/
}
```

До if я ставил echo и оно выводилось и после него я тоже ставил echo и оно тоже выводилось, но после строчки в которой мы хотим вернуть переменную $t вылезает ошибка(пытался возвращать способом через "echo $t;" и "$output = $t_fetch_assoc();
echo json_encode($output);" в обоих из них вылазит ошибка. 
Теперь немного уточнений, вдруг поможет: сначала случайно прописал присваивание вот таким образом "$output = $t-fetch_assoc();" и у меня не вылезало ошибки, но выводилась только первая строка массива. Спасите, помогите, пожалуйста!!!

Comment: `$output = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t);`

Comment: Быть не может, это опять вы, неужели опять на помощь пришли? После изменения запроса к тому формату, что указали вы ошибка не вылезает, но данные передаются некорректно(выводится только первая строка из выборки), или же обрабатываются на поступлении некорректно.

Comment: Да, это снова я ))) Помните последний пост? Вам надо просто получить тут `$t`, а `mysqli_fetch_assoc($t)` обрабатывать через `while` )

Comment: примерно так: `    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t)) {тут действие с каждом строкой из БД}?>`

Comment: @Denis640Kb секунду, сейчас скину прошлый вопрос где это подробнее расписывается мною. Я пытался так сделать, по вашему примеру так сказать, но ajax как то поменял правила игры.  [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084602/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно, почему Вы решили использовать `ajax`. Но если есть критичная необходимость в этом, то в данном случае, Вам надо писать `$output = $t->fetch_assoc();` вместо `$t_fetch_assoc();`

Comment: ajax я использую для того, что б узнать что то новое) если смотреть дальше по коду, то "output" потом переместится в блок Polina_time если я верно понял эту строчку "$("#Polina_time").html(response);" , если это тако, то у меня вопрос: почему же тогда не обрабатывается этот кусок кода '<div id="Polina_time" class="label_time_box"><?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($output)) {echo '<label class="label-date"><input type="radio"  id="ID_Polina_time" name="Polina_time" value=" '.$row['time'].' ">
<snap class="info_of_time">'.$row['date'].' </snap></label>';}?></div>'?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104647/discussion-between-denis640kb-and-kirzzz).

Answer (score -1):

Обрабатывайте `mysqli_fetch_assoc` в цикле, потому что он возвращает по одной строке результата при каждом вызове.

```
while($output = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t)) {
        $arr[] = $output;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

А также помните, что подобная обработка данных

```
$query = "SELECT time FROM `#desavir_Полина` WHERE date ='$date_Polina' ORDER BY time";
$t = mysqli_query($connect, $query); //Отправляем запрос
```

Создает в вашем коде уязвимость к атаке с использованием SQL-инъекции. Чтобы избежать этого, рекомендую как минимум обернуть дату в `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
 $master = mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['master’]);
 $date_Polina = mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST['Polina_date’]);
```

Советую почитать документацию PHP по mysqli.

Comment: Как возможно произвести SQL атаку если у меня нет полей для ввода данных, пользователи могут лишь выбирать данные из предоставленных мною.

Comment: Это очень плохой ответ. выводить несколько джейсон строк подряд нет смысла - ни один парсер эту кашу не поймет. Функции mysql_real_escape_string в языке РНР **нет**. А даже когда и была, она не была предназначена для защиты от уязвимостей, и никогда не должна использоваться для этой цели.

Comment: @Kirzzz как много тебе предстоит ещё узнать... Начни отсюда: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke

Comment: @Ипатьев, чуток подправил.

Answer (score -1):

Php-функции работы с JSON не работают в кодировке, отличной от UTF-8. Проверьте кодировку